# Solr: facets merge based on mapper

Tags: solr

I was wondering if there's a way in Solr 4 or higher, to merge facets together based on a mapper. I have a lot of products inside my database with terms (inside the taxonomy "color" for example) which actually mean the same. For example the color red is described as:

- red
- bordeaux
- light red
- dark red

I would like to merge such terms, cause I don't want to bother the user with hundreds of choices, when I can reduce that number to dozens. I'm trying to figure out what's the best way to do this, create a separate table inside my database (used to map the id's of terms together) or use functionality in Solr to do this on index-time. I read something about [Pivot Facets](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HierarchicalFaceting#Pivot_Facets), but I guess that's the way to go if there is already an hierarchy? Because those different terms of red are just flat (are not grouped together, yet). Any advices?

**EDIT:**

Guess I found a solution: http://www.wunderkraut.com/blog/how-to-combine-two-facet-items-in-facet-api/2015-03-26. Any thoughts about this? Looks good to me though.

Comment: The approach you've linked to only works if the documents are in distinct groups, and would break down if the field is multivalued (as a document can belong to several of the facet buckets in that case). Synonyms might be more helpful.

Comment: So you suggest to group them based on a synonym list. In that case I could create a separate database table in my RDBMS, which I use as a synonym list, right?

Comment: That could be a solution, yes - and just retrieve the normalized value when querying the DB, or you could use the Synonym filter in Solr - but that requires handling the synonym file externally from your existing database. If you want to integrate it with an existing web interface, it might be easier to fetch the synonym with a join when importing.